# What is the 'tf' alternative?

Tags: fonts, luatex, context

ConTeXt falls back to Latin Modern on this:

```
\definefontfamily [mainface] [rm] [Notexist]

\setupbodyfont[mainface]
\starttext
What font is this?
\stoptext
```

and offers this error from selectfont:

```
> The requested font 'Notexist' has no files for the 'tf' alternative, Latin Modern is used instead.
```

What is the `tf` alternative and can `mtxrun --script font` tell me beforehand what strings will work instead of **Notexist**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could select a specific font for the `tf` alternative to make it work.

```
\definefontfamily [mainface] [rm] [Notexist] [tf=file:texgyrepagella-regular]

\setupbodyfont[mainface]
\starttext
What font is this?
\stoptext
```

Of course it is better if you plug in a valid font name instead of `Notexist`.  Therefore you need to know the font name.  You can get a list of available fonts using

```bash
$ mtxrun --script font --list --all
```

The last column has the file in which the font is stored.  You can use `otfinfo` to get the font name.

```bash
$ otfinfo -a `kpsewhich texgyrepagella-regular.otf`
TeXGyrePagella
```

This name you then plug into `\definefontfamily`.

```
\definefontfamily [mainface] [rm] [TeXGyrePagella]

\setupbodyfont[mainface]
\starttext
What font is this?
\stoptext
```

(You can also use spaces, i.e. `TeX Gyre Pagella`.  As far as I know spaces are just discarded by the font loader.)

Comment: It would be nice to know what `tf` stands for.

Comment: @egreg I believe `tf` stands for »text font«.